# Zoom na interface do Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

No Windows nós seguramos o `ctrl` e utilizamos o `scroll` do mouse para aumentar ou diminuir a fonte (aproximar ou desaproximar).

No linux não achei essa função. Como dou zoom na interface do android studio?

Comment: Você quer dizer dar zoom no editor de codigo ou na simulacao da tela?

Comment: Aqui ensina a aumentar o tamanho da fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563979/zooming-editor-window-android-studio

Comment: Procurei mas não achei o `Preferences` como no link, mas achei em `Editor > General` Opção `Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel`. Obrigado !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No menu principal: `File > Settings`

Na janela "Settings": `Editor > General`

Marcar opção: `Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]